# Join table with a subquery result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create forum using PHP and Mysql. I have these two tables:

**Forum Topic**

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| project     | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| title       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_locked   | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| ForumTopic  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and **Forum Comment**

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| usr        | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| content    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_deleted | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ForumTopic | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

There are root topics, that contain children topics. Children topics can only contain comments. If ForumTopic (inside Forum_topic table, yeah I know bad naming) column is null, then it is a Root. Otherwise it contains ID of a root forum topic.

What I need is one query, that outputs number of Topics in each root category (category = root topic), number of comments for each root category (that means comments of all children topics sumarized) and finaly, whole row of last comment of category that is not deleted (is_deleted = 0).
What I have so far is this:

```
SELECT ID as topicId
     , (select count(*) 
          FROM `forum_topic` 
         where ForumTopic = topicId) as TopicCount
     , (SELECT count(*) 
          FROM `forum_comment` 
         where ForumTopic in (SELECT ID 
                                FROM `forum_topic` 
                               where ForumTopic = topicId) 
         ORDER 
            BY created desc) as postNumber
     , (SELECT ID FROM `forum_comment` 
         where ForumTopic in (SELECT ID 
                                FROM `forum_topic` 
                               where ForumTopic = topicId) 
         ORDER 
            BY created desc limit 1) as lastPostId 
  FROM `forum_topic` 
 where ForumTopic IS NULL 
   and project is null
```

With following output:

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
| topicId | TopicCount | postNumber | lastPostId |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
|       1 |          5 |         15 |         43 |
|       2 |          1 |          2 |         13 |
|       3 |          8 |          2 |         30 |
|       4 |          0 |          0 |       NULL |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I used subqueries to get this result, which is pretty close to what I need. But Instead of lastPostId(s) I really need the rows with that ID. So I tried to join with table of comments and use lastPostId as a column to join on, but it does not work.
Here is my attempt of joining

```
SELECT forum_topic.ID as topicId, (select count(*) FROM `forum_topic` where ForumTopic = topicId) as TopicCount,(SELECT count(*) FROM `forum_comment` where ForumTopic in (SELECT ID FROM `forum_topic` where ForumTopic = topicId) ORDER BY created desc) as postNumber,(SELECT ID FROM `forum_comment` where ForumTopic in (SELECT ID FROM `forum_topic` where ForumTopic = topicId) ORDER BY created desc limit 1) as lastPostId 
FROM `forum_topic`
join forum_comment on lastPostId = forum_comment.id
where forum_topic.ForumTopic IS NULL and forum_topic.project is null
```

This returns `1054 - Unknown column 'lastPostId' in 'on clause'`

How can I get this last comment row?

EDIT: Sample data can be found here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b65cfa/1

and expected result should be [image: expected result] .

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Sorry it is a MySQL, MSSQL was a suggestion I thoughtlessly clicked.

Comment: Add some sample table data as well, having matching expected result.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks! I was just looking for a tool to share some table data. I will add some sample data (sorry I didnt think of that).

Comment: Also, given that ID, ForumTopic, created, and project are the only columns relevant to this problem, there's really no point telling us about the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you join a query not a table without alias

So you need to wrap your query with a alias like this

```
    (SELECT forum_topic.ID as topicId
        , (select count(*) FROM `forum_topic` where ForumTopic = topicId) as TopicCount
        ,(SELECT count(*) FROM `forum_comment` where ForumTopic in (SELECT ID FROM `forum_topic` where ForumTopic = topicId) ORDER BY created desc) as postNumber
        ,(SELECT ID FROM `forum_comment` where ForumTopic in (SELECT ID FROM `forum_topic` where ForumTopic = topicId) ORDER BY created desc limit 1) as lastPostId 
        FROM `forum_topic` where forum_topic.ForumTopic IS NULL and forum_topic.project is null) A
```

Now you have new table A from your query and you perform join between A and forum_comment

```
    Select A.topicId
        ,A.TopicCount
        ,A.postNumber
        ,A.lastPostId
            from (SELECT forum_topic.ID as topicId
                    , (select count(*) FROM `forum_topic` where ForumTopic = topicId) as TopicCount
                    ,(SELECT count(*) FROM `forum_comment` where ForumTopic in (SELECT ID FROM `forum_topic` where ForumTopic = topicId) ORDER BY created desc) as postNumber
                    ,(SELECT ID FROM `forum_comment` where ForumTopic in (SELECT ID FROM `forum_topic` where ForumTopic = topicId) ORDER BY created desc limit 1) as lastPostId 
                    FROM `forum_topic` where forum_topic.ForumTopic IS NULL and forum_topic.project is null) A

                join forum_comment on A.lastPostId = forum_comment.id
```

Comment: Ugh! The cure looks worse than the disease :-(

Comment: @KhánhBùiĐức Could you please describe how and why it works?

Comment: @Kudlas I have updated answer and explain your problem more detail. However, I focus on fixing error joining but not read detail about your query purpose